# Calling C++ Functions in MASM Linker Error

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm

So I am currently trying to run external C++ functions from an assembly program. I have assembly programs running properly, but I keep getting a linker error saying:

"Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _testFunc@0 referenced in function __main@0"

I'm wondering why I am getting this error, I assume it's because I'm somehow incorrectly importing my C++ function into my asm program, but I've seen other people do it in a similar way.

Here's my assembly code:

```
; Created with MASM
.386

.MODEL FLAT, stdcall

.STACK 100h

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

extern testFunc : proto

.CODE
_main PROC

    call testFunc
    xor edi, edi

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

_main ENDP
END
```

and my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void _main();

extern "C" void testFunc()
{
    cout << "Hello world";
}

int main()
{
    _main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What C compiler? MSVC?

Comment: If this is normal Windows, the asm symbol name for `foo` is `_foo` in 32-bit code (not 64-bit).  So in asm, your `_main` definition is defining the C function `main`, not `_main`, unless MASM is adding another level of mangling.  Best to pick something totally different, like `asm_main` that isn't going to conflict unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes, using visual studio community 2019. Even if I change that, it says that Function Definition "asm_main" is not found. I feel I am missing something fundamental to understanding this.

Comment: Wow. I wasn't returning the function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `.MODEL FLAT, stdcall`. You should define the function

```
extern "C" __stdcall void testFunc()
```

Comment: Is this not what I'm doing here? "extern testFunc : proto"

Comment: You are not doing `extern testFunc : proto c` and your declaring default stdcall.

Comment: I think I realize what you meant, however I'm still getting an error saying "Symbol language attribute conflict: testFunc".

Comment: @Suezzeus: That's a different error, though; this answer does correctly fix the symbol-name mangling for stdcall functions (including `@n` with the number of bytes popped on return).

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Well thanks for explaining this portion. I believe I understand! I will just troubleshoot it for a while.